# can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)

Tags: docker, nginx, openshift

I'm trying to deploy an Angular application onto Openshift (i.e an angular docker container on Openshift). However, I'm facing difficulty modifying the `default.conf` file within nginx in the container, which I think also caused the error at line 9.

Here's the error log on Openshift:
[image]

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/ng-adminx /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

For context,

1. I'm not familiar with how permissions work on Openshift.
2. Also, this build works perfectly fine locally but fails on Openshift.

I think `chmod` or `chown` might be the solution. Would greatly appreciate any suggestion on how I should modify my dockerfile or navigate this! Thanks!

Comment: Does your container *need* to modify `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` at run-time? Wouldn’t it be possible to make the changes during the build? That would work better in OpenShift...

Comment: @Stephen it seems that nginx needs to modify this file at startup time. I have no clue why or if this can be disabled

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `chmod` to be able to modify the default.conf file.

For simplicity, you can use `chmod 777 <filepathname>`.

How does 777 come about? You can think of it as the permissions for read, write, execute for file owner, group and user respectively. 1 = allowed. 0 = not allowed.

So 7 in binary is 111.

| file owner | group | other users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rwx | rwx | rwx |
| 111 | 111 | 111 |

Comment: Formatting is off. Think of it as a table with 1st row "file owner", "group", "other users" and the 2nd row with the permissions for read, write, execute, and the 3rd row with the access flags.